# Best way to map one value to many

Tags: c#

I was wondering about the best way to map one value to many in a dictionary (or some other structure) in C#.

What I wanted to do is something like this:

```
public GenreToEntity = new Dictionary<string, string[]>()
{
    { "filmes", ["Filme"] },
    { "programas", ["Jornalismo", "Variedade", "Série/seriado"] }
};
```

But it should be static, so I don't want to add values line by line.
Is that possible?

Comment: "But it should be static, so I don't want to add values line by line." I don't understand what one has to do with the other.

Comment: "Is that possible?" Yes. Did you try? What problem did encounter?

Comment: would be nice to rephrase the question. Now seems blurry

Comment: What you have is close. You just need to tweak it slightly: `{ "programas", new[] { "Jornalismo", "Variedade", "Série/seriado" } }` Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @itsme86 yes! something like this

Comment: I would prefer a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`.

Comment: @TaW Why? Can you explain your preference?

Comment: List<T> is much more flexible than arrays. Check out the methods!

Comment: @TaW Just in case, I'm going with List<string> then. Thanks

Comment: @TaW So you just always use lists over arrays then? Even if there's no chance you'll be adding or removing elements at runtime? Just a collection of values that won't change?

Comment: Yes, pretty much. I'm not often sure my collections will never change or grow..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it! The missing part was what @itsme86 suggested:

```
public static Dictionary<string, List<string>> EntityToGenre = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>()
{
    { "filmes", new List<string>() {"Filme"} },
    { "novelas", new List<string>() {"Novela"} },
    { "programas", new List<string>() {"Jornalismo", "Variedade", "Série/seriado", "Outros" } }
};
```